# How to validate/verify .desktop files?

Tags: freedesktop, .desktop, xdg

I have a couple of `.desktop` files that aren't working as expected or not at all. I can't see any error anywhere and asking for help on each one seems unproductive. Is there a way I can verify that I'm using the correct syntax in the file, that it complies with the FreeDesktop standard, so I can apply specific fixes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are looking for the `desktop-file-validate` tool provided by the [desktop-files-utils package](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils/) in your distribution. It check for syntax, using reserved words/characters, in summary, that it complies with the [Desktop Entry specification](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec). Here's a example of a bad .desktop file:

```
➜  ~  desktop-file-validate asdf.desktop 
asdf.desktop: error: value "cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $*" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '&' outside of a quote
asdf.desktop: error: value "cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $*" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '&' outside of a quote
asdf.desktop: error: value "cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $*" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '$' outside of a quote
asdf.desktop: error: value "cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin && bash sqldeveloper $*" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '*' outside of a quote
asdf.desktop: hint: value item "GNOME" in key "Categories" in group "Desktop Entry" can be extended with another category among the following categories: GTK
asdf.desktop: error: value "GNOME;Oracle;Utility;Development;" for key "Categories" in group "Desktop Entry" contains an unregistered value "Oracle"; values extending the format should start with "X-"
asdf.desktop: hint: value "GNOME;Oracle;Utility;Development;" for key "Categories" in group "Desktop Entry" contains more than one main category; application might appear more than once in the application menu
asdf.desktop: error: value "s.0.m.t.h.i.n.g" for key "Version" in group "Desktop Entry" is not a known version
```

Which in good files like `caribou-autostart.desktop` won't show anything.

Comment: FTR `desktop-file-validate` may show no errors but still might not work at all due to an invalid entry on `Exec`.