# .desktop file not working

Tags: kde, desktop, desktop-environment

I wrote the following `.desktop` file for my application named Qtag:

```
[Desktop entry]
Name=Qtag
Comment=Audio tag editor
Exec=qtag
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/Qtag.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Multimedia;
Version=1.0
Type=Application
```

I copied it to `/usr/share/applications`, but I still cannot find my app in the menu (I use KDE Plasma 5 application launcher). When I try to open the file in Dolphin (the KDE file manager), it says that there is no `Type=...` entry in the file.
I use KDE Plasma 5. The executable and the icon are in the right places (qtag is in `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: change [Desktop entry] to [Desktop Entry], note capital E.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line needs to be `[Desktop Entry]`, with a capital `E`. Otherwise the file isn't recognized as a desktop entry. Dolphin is looking for the `Type=` line in the `[Desktop Entry]` section — this could use a more explicit error message!

You shouldn't put files under `/usr` (except under `/usr/local`), that's for your distribution. For your own desktop entry files, use `~/.local/share/applications`.

---

If you put `.desktop` files in random places, [they need to be executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419610/permission-of-a-desktop-file) — that's a security measure, to avoid accidentally running arbitrary code from files downloaded from the Internet. That doesn't apply if you put the file in a directory that's dedicated to destkop entry files such as `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`. You can add `#!/usr/bin/xdg-open` at the beginning to make the file a valid, executable script which will launch the application when executed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But there is no /usr/share/local/applications directory in my system. Should I create it, then?

Comment: @amethystAnt I never mentioned a directory `/usr/share/local/applications`. That's `.local/share/applications` (note the initial dot) from your home directory.

Comment: Adding on here that the `.desktop` file actually has to be in `.local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`, symlinks will not work. (Even symlinks with an executable bit set.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the validation tool [desktop-file-validate](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils/). It can find your typo and checks for more common mistakes.

```
$ desktop-file-validate qtag.desktop 
test.desktop: error: first group is not "Desktop Entry"
test.desktop: error: file contains group "Desktop entry", but groups extending the format should start with "X-"
```

(see also: [How to validate/verify .desktop files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156892/how-to-validate-verify-desktop-files))