# How do I debug a .desktop file?

Tags: .desktop

I have a `.desktop` file to start a python program in a specific conda environment, like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Qutebrowser
GenericName=Web Browser
Comment=View and edit files
MimeType=text/html;
Exec=bash -c "source /vol/home/kaipingga/anaconda3/bin/activate qutebrowser; qutebrowser"
Icon=/vol/home/kaipingga/.config/qutebrowser.svg
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Network;Utility;X-Python;
StartupWMClass=Qutebrowser
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.20
```

This used to work, but I tweaked my python environment recently.

Now, in a terminal the same command

```
$ bash -c "source /vol/home/kaipingga/anaconda3/bin/activate qutebrowser; qutebrowser"
```

runs the application, but the `.desktop` file does not. **How do I find out due to what error that is?**

My other `.desktop` files run fine, I assume something goes wrong with my Python environment, which is quite hackish for the moment (which is the main reason to run this in a dedicated `conda` environment to start with).

Zachary Brady originally suggested (but there are [issues](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343896)) `xdg-open` might run `.desktop` files, but it gives me a message box saying

> *Error*
>
> **Failed to add a plugin to the panel**
>
> No running instance of xfce4-panel was found

both for this `.desktop` and for another one that otherwise works. (I'm running plain Ubuntu, no xfce).

Comment: I deleted my answer after reading more into it [`xdg-open` has been bugged for quite a while](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343896) and only opens the desktop icons in text editors...

Comment: It turns out that the problem was an unsubstituted `~` (appearing as “`~`”, not as “`/home/anaphory`”) in the Python path, which I found out by adding `env > check;` in the middle of the command. But I'm sure there is a better way to debug this!

Comment: Desktop files are executed via menus, panels, or file managers. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the validation tool [desktop-file-validate](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/desktop-file-utils/) to find more problems.

(see also: [How to validate/verify .desktop files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156892/how-to-validate-verify-desktop-files))

```
# Result for your example
$ desktop-file-validate qutebrowser.desktop 
test.desktop: hint: value "Network;Utility;X-Python;" for key "Categories"
in group "Desktop Entry" contains more than one main category; application
might appear more than once in the application menu
```

Comment: That could be a useful program. Alas I tried it with a deliberately non-existant file path for the `Icon` and it reported nothing wrong.

Answer (score 8):

I normally add the following to see what is being executed:

```
Terminal=true
TerminalOptions=\s--noclose
```

Comment: Please note: [TerminalOptions has been deprecated](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#deprecated-items)

Comment: @Lockszmith do you know what should be used instead? The documentation seems only to say that TerminalOptions is deprecated, but it does not say why, or what to use instead.

Comment: @gillesB take a look [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/keep-terminal-window-open-after-running-a-desktop-launcher-4175722256-print/) - at the bottom, the suggestion to add `; read -n1` to the command might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux Mint, the File Manager service is named `nemo`, nemo can be exited by issuing:

```
nemo -q
```

With your file manager stopped, you can open it in a terminal

```
nemo
```

It will now print its log to this terminal, when you go to open your *.desktop file, you should be able to see the stdout of your *.desktop's Exec line.

Comment: Oh, and when your done debugging, Ctrl+C  the terminal running nemo, and open it via your start menu, or relog your desktop session.

Comment: It is rather the file manager of Cinnamon desktop which is maintained by the mint project https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo

Answer (score 1):

I've been debugging a desktop file and found this useful article on the archlinux website.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/desktop_entries#Run_a_desktop_file_from_a_terminal

> If `gtk3` is installed, run `gtk-launch application.desktop`.
> Or install the `dex` package and run `dex /path/to/application.desktop`.

It helped me see there was something wrong when misquoting my arguments. But in my case, I've got a successful result with `gtk-launch application.desktop` but not when launching through the Ubuntu 20.04 launcher

Answer (score 0):

`xdg-open` and `exo-open` are used for opening files (in their respective associated program). They were never meant to execute anything on their own. For executing the command defined by a desktop, you may use [dex](https://github.com/jceb/dex).